# Flutter - Callback function does not get called after redirecting from another page

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

      class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
        const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

        @override
        State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
      }

      class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container(child: ChildOne(someFunction: someFunction));
        }

        someFunction(dateTime) {
          //
        }
      }

      class ChildOne extends StatefulWidget {
        const ChildOne({Key? key, this.someFunction}) : super(key: key);
        final Function? someFunction;

        @override
        State<ChildOne> createState() => _ChildOneState();
      }

      class _ChildOneState extends State<ChildOne> {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: ChildTwo(someFunction: widget.someFunction),
          );
        }
      }

      class ChildTwo extends StatefulWidget {
        const ChildTwo({Key? key, this.someFunction}) : super(key: key);
        final Function? someFunction;

        @override
        State<ChildTwo> createState() => _ChildTwoState();
      }

      class _ChildTwoState extends State<ChildTwo> {
        @override
        void initState() {
          super.initState();
          WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
              (widget.someFunction != null)
                  ? widget.someFunction!(DateTime.now())
                  : () {});
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Container();
        }

        someOtherFunction() {
          widget.someFunction!(DateTime.now());
        }
      }
```

The first time the HomeScreen loads, everything works fine.
After I redirect to the HomeScreen from some other screen, the someFunction doesn't get called. How can I make it get called again?

SomeOtherScreen:

```
        ///After an API call....

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {

          Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
        }
```

Comment: What are you using for navigation

Comment: Try using `VoidCallback`  instead of  `Function`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Navigator.popAndPushNamed();

Comment: Can you update the question by adding routing

Comment: @Davis I have to pass a parameter, can I do that with VoidCallback?